# How to get the uploaded file in Controller which is uploaded through yii\helpers\Html::fileInput in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In my form I have used below code:

```
<?php echo Html::fileInput('imageFile', '', array('id' => 'contentForm_imageFile' )) ?>
```

and I tried to get the file in the controller with below code:

```
$newsModel->imageFile=UploadedFile::getInstance(Yii::$app->request->post('imageFile'), 'imageFile');
    $newsModel->imageFile->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$newsModel->file->basename.'.'.$newsModel->file->extension );
```

But I am getting this error when using above code to save the file:

> Call to a member function saveAs() on null

since the API document of `yii\web\UploadedFile` says that:

> getInstance() Returns an uploaded file for the given model attribute,
>   The file should be uploaded using
>   yii\widgets\ActiveField::fileInput().

So how can I get the uploaded file which is uploaded through `yii\helpers\Html::fileInput`?

Answer (score 3):

You can get uploaded file without model using [getInstanceByName()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile#getInstanceByName()-detail)

```
$newsModel->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('imageFile');
$newsModel->imageFile->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$newsModel->file->basename.'.'.$newsModel->file->extension );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an official example for your situation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Please double check your code:

1. First of all is there an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag?
2. Next, see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstance()-detail for parameters of getInstance. It requires model instance as first parameter and field name as second parameter.
3. Check that your server receives
   file that you send. Just `var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

To form add `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'`

In view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput(['id' => 'contentForm_imageFile']) ?>
```

Or

```
<?= Html::activeFileInput($model, 'imageFile', ['id' => 'contentForm_imageFile']) ?>
```

In Controller

```
$newsModel->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($newsModel, 'imageFile');
$newsModel->imageFile->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$newsModel->file->basename.'.'.$newsModel->file->extension );
```